# Returning 2 different strings

Tags: java, string, return

Is it possible to do what this code is trying to do (Current code format causes an error)

```
public String fileStream(){
    Object[] yesNo = {"Yes",
          "No",};
int nn = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Would you like to use previously entered data?","Welcome Back?",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, yesNo,yesNo[1]);
    if (nn == 0){
        String savedBallNumber = readFromFile();
        return savedBallNumber;
    }
    if (nn == 1){
        String ballNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number of balls you want on the screen:");
        return ballNumber;
    }
}
```

Error I get when I hover over fileStream is "This method must return a result of type String"

Comment: If you're getting an error, please post it.

Comment: You'll probably need to return a value at the end of the function too.  (The compiler is probably not smart enough to know that there are only two possibilities for `nn`.)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: extra commas are allowed in array declarations.

Comment: Updated with the code, sorry guys!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: more on this can be found at [JLS §10.6. Array Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6): `A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array initializer and is ignored.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is your code has returns in two if blocks, but has no else block meaning that thee's a chance that the method will end without returning anything:

For example:

```
public String someMethod {
  if (a) {
    return "foo";
  }
  if (b) {
    return "bar";
  }
}
```

What does it return if neither a nor b are true.

Solution: change the last if block to an else block:

```
public String fileStream() {
  Object[] yesNo = { "Yes", "No"};
  int nn = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
        "Would you like to use previously entered data?", "Welcome Back?",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
        yesNo, yesNo[1]);
  if (nn == 0) {
     String savedBallNumber = readFromFile();
     return savedBallNumber;
  } else {
     String ballNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number of balls you want on the screen:");
     return ballNumber;
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove an extra comma in array as well.

Comment: @PM77-1: more on this can be found at [JLS §10.6. Array Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6): `A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array initializer and is ignored.`

Comment: Didn't know it was *officially* allowed. Thx.